# When I'm typing a text in English, it gets underlined and behaves bizarrely

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, locale, input-method

I have Russian and US English locales. When I'm typing a text in English, it gets underlined until I press <kbd>Space</kbd> or some other special keys. When it's underlined, it's kind of invisible to the application where I'm typing it in. For example, in Sublime Text, it isn't even displayed until I press <kbd>Space</kbd>. In a browser it won't suggest me a URL until I press <kbd>Space</kbd>. It kind of gets buffered — saved in a temporary buffer and then released. And other bizarre stuff like this.

This doesn't happen always, sometimes, around 10% of the time, it works properly, I don't know what it depends on. And it doesn't happen, as far as I can remember, with Russian at all.

It's Arch, XFCE. I've done a bit of a search and haven't found anything anything related to this behaviour.

Comment: I would talk with the Sublime or XFCE guys/foruns to find where to file a bug, and disable the dictionary/autocorrect for a while. Maybe it is a know bug, and there is already a workaround.

Comment: Sounds like a bug or misconfiguration in your input method. Check your input method settings.

Comment: @Gilles, check what ?

Comment: A good start would be to set `LOCALE=C` (or better, unsetting the LOCALE environment variables altogether) and then configure both `Sublime` and the browser with russian spelling.  I assume you have `extra/firefox-i18n-ru` installed.  As for sublime, i never used it but it shall have it own spelling configuration too.  Also, for the purpose of testing, to make sure that your browser/editor is using the locale you think is using start it from a terminal emulator.

Comment: @grochmal, this happens in chrome also.

Comment: @Gilles, check what ?

Comment: @Oskar : He means that you have an input method (e.g. English-Us, Anty-Japanese, etc); you configure your available methods with `uim-pref-gtk`. It looks like you may have a non-English input method selected.

Comment: I'm having these problems too: and when I type words with accents or other special keys (like ç in Brazilian Portuguese), the accent simply does not show up (and if I type a space, the accent char appear, but after the letter, like [a'] instead of [á]. It does not happen on my terminal (urxvt), only on Chrome (didn't test on Firefox). Ah, I'm using Debian sid.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 28):

I also had this same issue (Arch XFCE). Basically what happens is it switches input methods whenever you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, which frequently accidentally happens when typing. To fix this, you have to change or remove this hotkey:

In a terminal window, type `uim-pref-gtk`, which is the settings for the UIM input method. Go to the `Global key bindings 1` section. Then, change the values for `[Global] on` and `[Global] off` by clicking edit on them both, and either changing or removing `<Shift>space`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you 10x. This is exactly what was happening with my system as well. Thanks @AHE!

Comment: Seconding @GuiAmbros, this is exactly what I needed! Thanks! Why was that so hard to find? I couldn't find it anywhere else...

Comment: Thank god I found this - worked for me! This really should probably not be turned on by default. Who knows how many people and hours are being spent on this nonsense.

Comment: Thank you so much. I originally thought this was a change to chrome and was furious. As I started to begin using other graphical application I realized the issue was not  isolated to chrome. Never had issues in my terminal which I thought was strange.